# hard to understand this macro

Tags: c, linux

```
#define __HAVE_ARCH_STRCPY
```

What's the meaning of `__HAVE_ARCH` ? I'm not a native speaker and I fail to find the meaning of it by google...(maybe this question is quite silly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining the `__HAVE_ARCH_XXXX` pre-processor tokens, it allows other locations in the OS kernel to test if the current hardware platform supports the `strcpy`, `memset`, etc. functionality.  You'll notice that on some platforms, this token is defined, and then a basic implementation of these functions are defined as inline functions along with the token, since on those platforms, the functionality is not provided by some other kernel library or kernel code module.  On other platforms, the functions are defined in some other code module, and may be simply declared as `extern` just after the pre-processor token.

Keep in mind that the kernel itself in Linux does not have access to the standard libc library, so these functions have to be defined separately from what you would typically use in a user-land application that is linked against libc.  Thus it's important to define what standard functions are present, and which ones are not, as it may vary from platform-to-platform.

Answer (score 2):

"This architecture has strcpy()".